# Running Appium with Cucumber on multiple iOS versions

Tags: java, ios, cucumber, appium, gherkin

I have an automation suite setup using Appium and Cucumber on a Mac (IDE = Eclipse).

I am keen to run my same gherkin tests against different versions of the iOS simulator.  I assumed the easiest way to do this would be to use different desiredCapabilities values.  However, I am not sure how to parameterise these values (so I can pass in the iOS version via the command line)?

Any ideas?

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can run Appium from the terminal very easily, setting desired capabilities from the terminal window.

Simply install appium to run on terminal:

$ npm install -g appium
$ appium &
(more details: http://appium.io/getting-started.html)

Then call the following from the terminal so you can see how to pass in desired capabilities
$ appium -help

So for example you might call the following:

$ appium --device-name 'iPhone 6'

Hope this helps others.